Asterisk can not register endpoint, the log say: wrong password
I dont know why I got this problem, can someone help?
<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.1.3:39681 --->
REGISTER sip:192.168.1.9:5060;transport=UDP SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.3:39681;branch=z9hG4bK-524287-1---6c7c9e51d91e7a9a;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:101@192.168.1.3:39681;rinstance=4768845210e4a444;transport=UDP>
To: <sip:101@192.168.1.9:5060;transport=UDP>
From: <sip:101@192.168.1.9:5060;transport=UDP>;tag=b6fc0802
Call-ID: dLyEjjMFY2z-j_HaePJkug..
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
Expires: 70
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, BYE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS, INFO, SUBSCRIBE
Supported: replaces, norefersub, extended-refer, timer, outbound, path, X-cisco-serviceuri
User-Agent: Z 5.3.7 rv2.9.30
Allow-Events: presence, kpml, talk
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (14 headers 0 lines) ---
Sending to 192.168.1.3:39681 (NAT)
Sending to 192.168.1.3:39681 (NAT)

<--- Transmitting (NAT) to 192.168.1.3:39681 --->
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.3:39681;branch=z9hG4bK-524287-1---6c7c9e51d91e7a9a;received=192.168.1.3;rport=39681
From: <sip:101@192.168.1.9:5060;transport=UDP>;tag=b6fc0802
To: <sip:101@192.168.1.9:5060;transport=UDP>;tag=as0c560803
Call-ID: dLyEjjMFY2z-j_HaePJkug..
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
Server: Asterisk PBX 16.8.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5, realm="asterisk", nonce="07fd5099"
Content-Length: 0


<------------>
Scheduling destruction of SIP dialog 'dLyEjjMFY2z-j_HaePJkug..' in 32000 ms (Method: REGISTER)

<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.1.3:39681 --->
REGISTER sip:192.168.1.9:5060;transport=UDP SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.3:39681;branch=z9hG4bK-524287-1---a3c359ac925b7132;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:101@192.168.1.3:39681;rinstance=4768845210e4a444;transport=UDP>
To: <sip:101@192.168.1.9:5060;transport=UDP>
From: <sip:101@192.168.1.9:5060;transport=UDP>;tag=b6fc0802
Call-ID: dLyEjjMFY2z-j_HaePJkug..
CSeq: 2 REGISTER
Expires: 70
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, BYE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS, INFO, SUBSCRIBE
Supported: replaces, norefersub, extended-refer, timer, outbound, path, X-cisco-serviceuri
User-Agent: Z 5.3.7 rv2.9.30
Authorization: Digest username="101",realm="asterisk",nonce="07fd5099",uri="sip:192.168.1.9:5060;transport=UDP",response="fe1dc7376c8182317bcf6781b77a0552",algorithm=MD5
Allow-Events: presence, kpml, talk
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (15 headers 0 lines) ---
Sending to 192.168.1.3:39681 (NAT)

<--- Transmitting (NAT) to 192.168.1.3:39681 --->
SIP/2.0 403 Forbidden
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.3:39681;branch=z9hG4bK-524287-1---a3c359ac925b7132;received=192.168.1.3;rport=39681
From: <sip:101@192.168.1.9:5060;transport=UDP>;tag=b6fc0802
To: <sip:101@192.168.1.9:5060;transport=UDP>;tag=as0c560803
Call-ID: dLyEjjMFY2z-j_HaePJkug..
CSeq: 2 REGISTER
Server: Asterisk PBX 16.8.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Length: 0


<------------>
[Apr 13 09:04:21] NOTICE[58]: chan_sip.c:28959 handle_request_register: Registration from '<sip:101@192.168.1.9:5060;transport=UDP>' failed for '192.168.1.3:39681' - Wrong password


